# Spring Sleuth stuck sending 10 percent of request to Zipkin

Tags: spring-cloud, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

By default Spring Sleuth only sends 10% of requests to Zipkin.  By setting `spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage` you can increase the percentage.  Unfortunately it is stuck at 10% regardless of what value I set it to.  I have tried 1.0, 0.5, 1, 100.

Output from `/env`

```
            "spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage": {
                "value": 1,
                "origin": "class path resource [application.yml]:77:19"
            }
```

Regardless of the value, when I make multiple requests, only 10% make it to Zipkin.

We are using version Finchley.M8 of Spring Cloud and 2.0.0.RELEASE of Spring Boot.

Below are relevant POM settings.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 9):

Ok we found the problem and also a work around.

It looks like all the documentation out there is wrong, at least for the version of Spring Cloud Sleuth we are using.  The correct property is not `spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage`.  The correct property is `spring.sleuth.sampler.probability`

And here is a workaround we found right before noticing that the property was wrong.

```
@Bean
public Sampler alwaysSampler() {
    return Sampler.ALWAYS_SAMPLE;
}
```

Here are some official documentation from Spring Cloud that contain the wrong property.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.0.0.M5/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html

Here is the source code that is being used and it is using `probability` not `percentage`.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/sampler/SamplerProperties.java

Comment: samplerProperties directory is changed to `https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/c795675cf93c666c3c13f9bbb9eadbde1f1aa775/spring-cloud-sleuth-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/SamplerProperties.java`